# Assigning to an array which is a member of struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

This question may be a duplicate. But I am asking it again because the solution provided there dint help me compile the code error free.

I have a following code snippet

```
    #include<stdlib.h>

    using namespace std;

    void initgrid();

    struct gridblock
    {
        bool occ;
        double col[3];
        double trans[3];
    }grid[10][19];

    void initgrid()
    {
        grid[0][0].occ=false;
        grid[0][0].trans={-23.0,0.0,-24.0};
        ....
    }

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        initgrid();
        return 0;
    }
```

when I compile the above snippet with `g++ <filename>.cpp -o test`

I have been shown the following warning followed by an error

[image]

I am looking for a solution to overcome this. I have tried initializer_list and memcpy but that dint work. The line number 17 is `grid[0][0].trans={-23.0,0.0,-24.0}`

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so firstly your initialisation is completely wrong! Secondly where is your declaration for your struct instance? Thirdly you are missing several semi-colons to close off statements, next you are accessing your arrays wrong, please look at my code ad work from that.

```
struct gridblock
{
    bool occ;
    double col[3];
    double trans[3];
}grid[10][19];

void initgrid(gridblock& grid[10][19])
{
    grid[0][0].trans[0] = 3.3;
    grid[0][0].trans[1] = 5.1;
    grid[0][0].trans[2] = 7.0;
    grid[0][0].occ = false;
    ....
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    gridblock grid;    

    initgrid(grid);
    return 0;
}
```

I would also recommend going through a beginner C++ book to learn these fundamental concepts, I get the feeling you have jumped ahead to structs way to fast!

Comment: Sorry i couldn't write a technically correct snippet. I had my struct instance in my struct sytax like "struct abc {member}a; "

Comment: Your advice is sound, but perhaps you should follow it too. Your code sample is badly broken and should not compile on a reasonable compiler.

Comment: @juanchopanza haven't coded in C++ for quite a while, please let me know or edit what is wrong

Comment: @juanchopanza also don't downvote when you don't provide information of what is wrong, that's not constructive at all.

Comment: The comment referred to your original answer. The main point is in my answer: arrays are not assignable or copyable. Also you were passing a `gridblock` object by value, which meant your init function held its own copy, failing to initialized anything on the caller side.

Comment: Are you certain arrays are not assignable? I could have swore that you can do something like `index[0] = 100;` or `int index[] = { 100, 101, 102 };` but it must be at initialisation which may be where I am wrong with the code

Comment: Yes I am. And to be clear, your current version also suffers from that problem. Do you have a compiler that accepts this code? I am curious to know which one, because it would constitute a compiler but (if it is old, that is not so important.) So `index[0] = 100;` is assigning to an `int` (or whatever `index[0]` is, not to an array. And `int index[] = {....};` is a special syntax for arrai declaration and initialization, which is fine. What you cannot do is say `int index2[3] = index;` for example.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have not enabled the C++11 compiler switch.  That capability is new.  The warning you is telling you to enable the switch.  Changing the code won't help.  You have to change the configuration of your compiler.

Comment: plus all of the other problems, really a more complete version of the code should be supplied as this code makes little sense and I have had to guess as to what he is trying to achieve

Comment: Enabling C++11 would make no difference here.

Comment: No kidding Matt?  Why are you writing to tell me about that?